# Create a (text) file using FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a notepad, however i want to save the file using the FolderBrowserDialog. Now i can't save the file because of this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The specified path is not supported.

this is the code i enterd:

```
private void Create_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to make the file", "Sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog openfiledalog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (openfiledalog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(openfiledalog1.SelectedPath);

                StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(files + "." + groupBox3);
                File.Write(textBox4);

            }
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: This ones: string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(openfiledalog1.SelectedPath);

                StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(files + "." + groupBox3);
                File.Write(textBox4);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few things here to cause problems:

- `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(openfiledalog1.SelectedPath);`

Here you read the existing files in that directory. I thought you wanted to *create* a file? IN that case you provide a destination path, e.g.

`var dest=Path.Combine(openfileDialog1.SelectedPath,"myfile.txt");`

- The following especially will not work:

`StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(files + "." + groupBox3);`

You are passing a string *array* here. You need to pass a string as argument, not an array. See above. Also you try to name it like (which?) existing file + an extension determined by some groupBox3?

- Writing the file, assuming that textBox4 contains the contents to be written, needs to be specified via the .Text property:

`File.Write(textBox4.Text);`

Please be specific as to which control or variable contains the desired output filename, which the contents, and what groupBox3 is supposed to provide.

**Edit:**

```
RadioButton suffix = groupBox3.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Checked);
if (suffix == null)
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid extension first");
else
{
    var extension = suffix.Text;
    FolderBrowserDialog openfiledalog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (openfiledalog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var dest = Path.Combine(openfiledalog1.SelectedPath, "NewFile." + extension);
        using (StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(dest, false))
        {
            File.Write(textBox4.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, explaned what the elements are: groupBox3= file extension selector (like .txt, .nfo, etc.). The textBox4 is indeed the text input.

Comment: OK, I've edited my response, as code in a comment does not look too pretty... :-)
**Make sure that groupBox3 actually holds a value**.

Comment: Sorry, the groupBox3 used with radiobuttons

Comment: I have adapted the final code in my answer above.
This should do the trick.